# create-react-native-app - eject does not create index.js

Tags: react-native, create-react-app, react-native-linking

I am new to React Native. I created my React Native app with `create-react-native-app`. But now I want to use some libraries which require me to link via `react-native link` so I decided to eject using `react-native eject`. However, when start the server with `react-native start` then run `react-native android` I got the following error on my Android emulator:

```
Cannot find entry file index.js in any of the root
```

What should I do to get the app running?

Comment: I am getting the same error - did you find out what the problem was?

Comment: Other people in the Expo CLI issue about this have the same problem. I also had it. I just had a blank project at that point, so I just ditched Expo and ended up doing `react-native init PROJECT_NAME`